# How can i get view path in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I create a helper and i want to get view's path in this helper code, How can i do that?

I try code below. It will use view that return from action. So If i use this helper in partial view it will get parent view name instead.

```
RazorView view = helper.ViewContext.View as RazorView;      
viewPath = view.ViewPath;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you need that??

Comment: try this ((System.Web.Mvc.RazorView)htmlHelper.ViewContext.View).ViewPath

Comment: @Shiv it's same thing as my code. if it's in partial view it will return parent view name not the partial one.

Comment: AFAIK, you can get the path with `string path = helper.ViewDataContainer as WebPageBase).VirtualPath;` but its not very elegant and you would have to parse the value

Comment: @StephenMuecke Add it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve the path of the view or partial view using

```
string path = (helper.ViewDataContainer as WebPageBase).VirtualPath;
```

This will return something like `~/Views/Home/MyPartial.cshtml`

Comment: What is 'helper' ?